# Setting up JDK 10 in IntelliJ IDEA: the selected directory is not a valid home for JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Has someone tried setting up JDK 10 on IntelliJ in MacOS?

When trying to do so, I am getting message as 
"the selected directory is not a valid home for JDK".

I have installed JDK 10 provided by oracle for MacOS

JDK intallation path on my machine is
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Are you sure about contents of /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk ? Subfolder /Contents/Home sounds weird to me. Under jdk folder there sould be other folders like bin/, lib/, etc.

Comment: @gorlok this is for MacOS, path looks valid

Comment: Make sure you run the latest IntelliJ IDEA version from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder version:2017* of intellij was installed on my machine, even after updating it has just moved to a higher version of 2017*
<br/>
**This worked for me**: Uninstalling version:2017* and installing [version:2018.2 (still in beta)](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) worked for me

Comment: 2018.1.4 (not beta) should also work fine: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.  2017 version has no proper support for Java 10 since it was released long before it.

Comment: Thank You @CrazyCoder, you can post the answer and I can mark it accepted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proper support for Java 10 requires IntelliJ IDEA 2018.x version. IntelliJ IDEA 2017.x versions may not detect Java installation path properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, but in Ubuntu. If you are in MAC, im sure its similar.
The thing is that firstly you must install the jdk and jre.

I have it in my /usr/lib/jvm

Then, after that, you must puth the variable $JAVA_HOME in your $PATH in the ~/.bashrc file at the end. But i found that after adding my jre and my jdk, my IDE didn't detect my jdk. So what i do to solve this in my IDE was:

In your command line:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

```
export JAVA_HOME='your/path/to/jdk/without/bin'
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If no problem was detected and all is fine, just do

```
java --version
```

If is detected, next, go to the other step:

=> Open your IDE. In this step, if your IDE doesn't recognize java version or SDK (as in my case), do the following

```
javac --version
```

This is where i solved the problem, becouse it looked like i didn't have javac, so I solved it with:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-<version>-jdk-headless
```

=> Then open your IDE and select the SDK you have just installed. Its like the IDE doesn't recognize de previus jdks.